# Vertx - EventBus send deprecated - in favor of what?

Tags: vert.x

We are migrating to vertx 3.8.0.

```
   /** @deprecated */
    @Fluent
    @Deprecated
    <T> EventBus send(String var1, Object var2, Handler<AsyncResult<Message<T>>> var3);
```

The method send is deprecated.

I reckon now the method [request](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/rxjava/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#request-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-io.vertx.core.Handler-) is  used.

Is this correct?
If so, what is the difference? It cannot be just the naming.

I couldn't find the changelog, reasoning via google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vert.x 4 will provide a future based asynchronous model while retaining compatibility with Vert.x 3.x callback model. Each callback method will have a corresponding future version, e.g:

```
client.connect(addr, ar -> ...);

Future<NetSocket> future = client.connect(addr);
```

For more details see the Vert.x [wiki](https://github.com/vert-x3/wiki/wiki/RFC:-Future-API).

In this process, some methods cannot be futurized correctly because having a callback implies different semantics. For the event bus `send` method, having a callback means a reply is expected, no callback means fire and forget.

This why the `send` with a callback has been deprecated in 3.8 and a new one named `request` has been introduced.